# jQuery can't find an element by class when I refresh the element with ajax

Tags: jquery

I want to upload an image dynamically and crop it after using jquery library.

Here is the code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('.preview').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '4:3', handles: true }); //this code is from crop library


        $('#photoimg').live('change', function()            { 
                   $("#preview").html('');
            $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                    target: '#preview'
    }).submit();

        });


    });
```

Here is HTML part

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
Upload your image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>
<div id='preview'>
 <img class="preview" src="uploads/1391586558.png" />
</div>
```

And the php part that updates the image

```
echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."'  class='preview'>";
```

Well i can crop the image at the beginning, but when it replaces with another one by ajax (with the same class name) it stop working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you refresh it with ajax you create a new element and this new element is plain. i stumpled upon this problem once

Comment: Yes i understand. But how can i select it now with selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of al  `$.live()` is deprecated you should use

```
$('#photoimg').on('change', function(){});
```

It isn't working because the element which you put `.imgAreaSelect.` on is removed.

You should enable it again when the `div#preview` is filled with your updated image.

```
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
    target: '#preview',
    success: function() { 
        $('#preview').find('.preview').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '4:3', handles: true });
    } 
}).submit();
```

entire example:

```
(function(){
    var imgAreaSettings = { aspectRatio: '4:3', handles: true };
    var preview_div = $("#preview"); // cache this one, it's used multiple times so makes searching DOM faster.

    $('#photoimg').on('change', function(){ 

        preview_div .html('');
        preview_div .html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');

        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#preview',
            success: function() { 
                preview_div.find('.preview').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '4:3', handles: true });
            } 
    }).submit();

})();
```

Comment: First of all - Thank you! Now it works. But i tried to use .on() and it not working, while with .live() it's perfect. May be my jquery version is old or something

Comment: 1.10.2 is the newest version try loading it by CDN: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call again the

```
$('.preview').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '4:3', handles: true });
```

after the image replacement.

Comment: you should add it in succes option, see my answer

Comment: Tim give the right answer, you need to add the `success` option and make the call to the `imgAreaSelect`